# CPT: multiple loops with different terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, customization, loop

I didn't finde the right code for 3 days... now i'm asking you:

I want to achieve the following:

Here my post query:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'tarife',
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__in' => $products
));
```

IF the **term** of my custom taxonomy[tarife] is '**info**'

than show **loop 1**

```
while($posts->have_posts()):
    $posts->the_post();
    $response .= 'loop1';
endwhile;
```

IF the **term** of my custom taxonomy[tarife] is '**glasfaser**'

than show **loop 2**

```
while($posts->have_posts()):
    $posts->the_post();
    $response .= 'loop2';
endwhile;
```

---

**EDIT:**

Now i have tried it like this but it shows me both loops if one of taxonomy exists.

```
$products = self::$productDefinitions[$result['Standorttyp']];
$posts_info = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'tarife',
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__in' => $products,
    'taxonomy' => 'info'
));

$posts_gf = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'tarife',
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__in' => $products,
    'taxonomy' => 'glasfaser'
));


if ( $posts_info->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $posts_info->have_posts() ) : $posts_info->the_post();    
        $response .= 'infos';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;

if ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $posts_gf->have_posts() ) : $posts_gf->the_post();    
        $response .= 'tarife';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
```

If I choose option 1 in the frontend, the result should be: 
tarife tarife tarife

If I choose option 2 in the frontend, the result should be: 
info

What i get:

option 1: info info info tarife tarife tarife

option 2: info tarife

Comment: You can set taxonmies and terms in `WP_Query`, not sure if I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have found the solution

I only have to add the right tax_query...

```
    $posts_info = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'tarife',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post__in' => $products,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tarif_kategorie',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'info',
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $posts_gf = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'tarife',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post__in' => $products,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tarif_kategorie',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'glasfaser',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```